# AWS CloudTrail: log getObject calls in specific S3 directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail

I'm trying to create a CloudTrail log for getObject calls to all files within a specific "directory" (I know) within S3. Unfortunately so far no logs have appeared at all after a few days.

These files are accessed by their public URL, and I'm assuming that when visiting this URL a getObject call is done behind the scenes. I've opened a few of the files just to make sure there were requests to log.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the log selector template I used:

```
[
  {
    "name": "FileReads",
    "fieldSelectors": [
      {
        "field": "eventCategory",
        "equals": [
          "Data"
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "resources.type",
        "equals": [
          "AWS::S3::Object"
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "resources.ARN",
        "startsWith": [
          "aws:s3:::[bucket-name-redacted]/[path-redacted]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "readOnly",
        "equals": [
          "true"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```